# Checking if each 'block' has less then 5 lines with specific character

Tags: bash

I have a file that has 5 'blocks' and looks like this:

```
AACP_AGRFC  Agrobacterium fabrum    A9CHM9  PDB; 2JQ4; NMR; -; A=1-83.
                    PDB; 4H2W_5GP.pdb; X-ray; 1.95 A; C/D=1-83.
                    PDB; 4H2X_G5A.pdb; X-ray; 2.15 A; C/D=1-83.
                    PDB; 4H2Y; X-ray; 2.10 A; C/D=1-83.

AADB1_KLEPN Klebsiella pneumoniae.  P0AE05  PDB; 4WQK_GOL.pdb; X-ray; 1.48 A; A=1-177.
                    PDB; 4WQL_GOL.pdb; X-ray; 1.73 A; A=1-177.
                    PDB; 5KQJ; NMR; -; A=1-177.

AAKB2_RAT   Rattus norvegicus   Q9QZH4  PDB; 2LU3; NMR; -; A=67-163.
                    PDB; 2LU4; NMR; -; A=67-163.
                    PDB; 4Y0G_GOL.pdb; X-ray; 1.60 A; A/B=74-155.
                    PDB; 4YEE_GOL.pdb; X-ray; 2.00 A; A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R=74-155.

AAPK2_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P54646  PDB; 2H6D; X-ray; 1.85 A; A=6-279.
                    PDB; 2LTU; NMR; -; A=282-339.
                    PDB; 2YZA; X-ray; 3.02 A; A=6-279.
                    PDB; 3AQV_TAK.pdb; X-ray; 2.08 A; A=6-279.
                    PDB; 4CFE; X-ray; 3.02 A; A/C=1-552.
                    PDB; 4CFF; X-ray; 3.92 A; A/C=1-552.
                    PDB; 4ZHX_4O7_C1V_C2Z.pdb; X-ray; 2.99 A; A/C=2-552.
                    PDB; 5EZV_C1V_C2Z_STU.pdb; X-ray; 2.99 A; A/C=2-347, A/C=397-552.
                    PDB; 5ISO_992_STU.pdb; X-ray; 2.63 A; A/C=1-552.

ABC3B_HUMAN Homo sapiens    Q9UH17  PDB; 2NBQ; NMR; -; A=187-382.
                    PDB; 5CQD_GOL.pdb; X-ray; 2.08 A; A/C=187-378.
                    PDB; 5CQH; X-ray; 1.73 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5CQI; X-ray; 1.68 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5CQK_GOL_PGE.pdb; X-ray; 1.88 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5TD5; X-ray; 1.72 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5TKM; X-ray; 1.90 A; A/B=1-191.
```

Each line is different in size but we are looking only for specific column, we are looking at columns where are `X-ray` and `NMR` (they are always in same column) and we want to check if under each 'block' there are `>=5` lines that under that column has `X-ray`. If it is the case then we want to print that block. If it is not the case then we want to remove whole block.  So expected result should look like this:

```
AAPK2_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P54646  PDB; 2H6D; X-ray; 1.85 A; A=6-279.
                    PDB; 2LTU; NMR; -; A=282-339.
                    PDB; 2YZA; X-ray; 3.02 A; A=6-279.
                    PDB; 3AQV_TAK.pdb; X-ray; 2.08 A; A=6-279.
                    PDB; 4CFE; X-ray; 3.02 A; A/C=1-552.
                    PDB; 4CFF; X-ray; 3.92 A; A/C=1-552.
                    PDB; 4ZHX_4O7_C1V_C2Z.pdb; X-ray; 2.99 A; A/C=2-552.
                    PDB; 5EZV_C1V_C2Z_STU.pdb; X-ray; 2.99 A; A/C=2-347, A/C=397-552.
                    PDB; 5ISO_992_STU.pdb; X-ray; 2.63 A; A/C=1-552.

ABC3B_HUMAN Homo sapiens    Q9UH17  PDB; 2NBQ; NMR; -; A=187-382.
                    PDB; 5CQD_GOL.pdb; X-ray; 2.08 A; A/C=187-378.
                    PDB; 5CQH; X-ray; 1.73 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5CQI; X-ray; 1.68 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5CQK_GOL_PGE.pdb; X-ray; 1.88 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5TD5; X-ray; 1.72 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5TKM; X-ray; 1.90 A; A/B=1-191.
```

PS. we cannot take `;` as a delimiter for columns but we know these columns where `X-ray` and `NMR` are located, are always `PDB; XXXX(.pdb); X-ray or NMR`.

Does anybody has an idea how this can be done in bash? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered a python script? It's probably better suited for this.

Comment: hm I have no experience in python at all..have some in perl, but still not enough to deal with this problem..

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for you comment. Do you mean "under each block"? About the columns..I am looking only to this specific one that have `X-ray` and `NMR`. I am only interested in counting number of `X-ray` within each block. So if number of `X-ray` is `>=5` within the block then print the whole block as it was at the beginning no changes..but if it is less then 5..then remove whole block, like in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your criterion can be expressed as the number of lines matching regular expression `/PDB; [^;]*; X-ray/` you could do something like

```
awk -vRS= -F'\n' '
  {c=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) c += $i ~ /PDB; [^;]*; X-ray/ ? 1 : 0} c >= 5
'
```

or (slightly neater, IMHO)

```
perl -F'\n' -00ne 'print unless (grep { /PDB; [^;]*; X-ray/ } @F) < 5'
```

Ex.

```
$ perl -F'\n' -00ne 'print unless (grep { /PDB; [^;]*; X-ray/ } @F) < 5' file
AAPK2_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P54646  PDB; 2H6D; X-ray; 1.85 A; A=6-279.
                    PDB; 2LTU; NMR; -; A=282-339.
                    PDB; 2YZA; X-ray; 3.02 A; A=6-279.
                    PDB; 3AQV_TAK.pdb; X-ray; 2.08 A; A=6-279.
                    PDB; 4CFE; X-ray; 3.02 A; A/C=1-552.
                    PDB; 4CFF; X-ray; 3.92 A; A/C=1-552.
                    PDB; 4ZHX_4O7_C1V_C2Z.pdb; X-ray; 2.99 A; A/C=2-552.
                    PDB; 5EZV_C1V_C2Z_STU.pdb; X-ray; 2.99 A; A/C=2-347, A/C=397-552.
                    PDB; 5ISO_992_STU.pdb; X-ray; 2.63 A; A/C=1-552.

ABC3B_HUMAN Homo sapiens    Q9UH17  PDB; 2NBQ; NMR; -; A=187-382.
                    PDB; 5CQD_GOL.pdb; X-ray; 2.08 A; A/C=187-378.
                    PDB; 5CQH; X-ray; 1.73 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5CQI; X-ray; 1.68 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5CQK_GOL_PGE.pdb; X-ray; 1.88 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5TD5; X-ray; 1.72 A; A=187-378.
                    PDB; 5TKM; X-ray; 1.90 A; A/B=1-191.
```